# Is it possible to create a file that cannot be deleted by an ordinary user even if all directories have 777 permission?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I'd like to know if I can create a file on a server that has all directories set to 777 permission, such that the no ordinary user (non-root) is able to delete the file. If so, do I have to be root user on the system, or can I do it as an ordinary user too?

My initial thoughts are, I should just be able to use "chmod 0444" on the file and that should take care of it.

I would have tried this out myself but I don't have access to a Linux server.

Comment: I wonder if there is a use case to this? Why not just deal with it by setting the directory permissions to something, less wide-open?

Comment: @ilkkachu take `/tmp` as an example. This folder is accessible for any user in a system. But it's undesirable for one user to delete temp files of other users. Then this problem arises.

Comment: @ddnomad, well, my point was mostly on the "all directories" part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may add the “sticky bit” (with `chmod +t`) to your directory. With this bit set, files in the directory can only be deleted by their owner.

You may also give the file the “immutable” attribute (with `chattr +i`). With this attribute, nobody can modify or delete the file.

Comment: @AutomationZombie Just curious, did you choose the “sticky bit” or the “immutable” attribute?